# Etymology of "drawback"

Tags: etymology

What's the etymology of "drawback"?

Most sources I've found give a date all the way back to the 1720s [1](https://www.etymonline.com/word/drawback), but with only vague explanation apart from the date.

Etymology Online says:

> "hindrance, disadvantage,"1720, from draw (v.) + back (adv.). The notion is of something that "holds back" success or activity.

Though that feels more like a definition than an etymology.

There's an earlier reference to a compound word verb form with at different meaning dating all the way back to the 1400s [2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drawback) but it's unclear if there's any relation, and there's similarly no explanation.

Comment: Please cite at least one source that provided no explanation IN your answer. Qestions that receive expert answers are those that also *show* research.

Comment: Your first link does give an explanation: "The notion is of something that "holds back" success or activity."

Comment: I regarded that (perhaps incorrectly) as a definition rather than an explanation. The word "draw" seems odd here, and specific. Updated to "vague".

Comment: Could it come from judicial legalese, where terms often have odd etymologies? I didn't read the examples, because you didn't quote them.

Comment: Compare *retreat*, German *Rückzug* and *draw-out* versus *hold-out*. *rück-* literally means *back*, that's the only reason for my notion. But also compare *Hinterhalt* (back/behind + hold), a trap, specifically an ambush, equivalently *Hintertreffen*, which is phonetically close to *draw*, chiefly in the phrase *in's Hintertreffen geraten* "to fall behind".

Comment: I'm sorry I can' makebthat an answer without due research, because a-priori it seems that draw and treffen are not thought to be related. I'd also compare *drag*, *accident, incident* (for *zusammentreffen*), and Ger. *streifen*, *streichen*, *Strich*, especially *Abstriche machen* (to take draw backs). This would imply to me a pre English origin--not for the term, but the concepts involved.

Comment: Think of "draw" in its more general sense of "pull, drag", not in the narrower specific sense of "sketch, depict".

Comment: @MarkBeadles already was, but it still seems odd. draw/pull back sounds very active whereas the idea of a drawback feels very passive. Etymology online unfortunately neither quotes it's reference nor links to it for context.

Comment: Compare also *abträglich* "detrimental", perhaps w.r.t. book-keeping, viz *eintragen, austragen, Betrag*, further *Betragen* "behaviour" (how to carry oneself). *trag-* and *drag* may be related. Why is someone called a *drag*, is it a *drag-down*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Drawback* is formed from the verb *draw*, meaning to pull, and the adverb *back*. The verb form meaning to retreat or recoil was indeed around since about 1400, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, and there's a nonce usage in noun form in 1619 that I haven't been able to duplicate in "[drawback, n. and adj.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57537)":

> 1619   E. M. Bolton tr. Florus Rom. Hist. ii. vi. 151   Fabius..got the nick-name, to bee called, The draw-backe, or Cunctator.

In effect, a draw-back *cunctates* or delays work.

The noun form comes more fully into English as a nominalization of a trade policy whereby import duties would be paid back on goods subsequently exported. The verb for a trader drawing back (taking back or receiving back) the duty payments they received was quickly nominalized.

Here is a 1699 source, "[An Account of rock-salt from the 25th of Decemb. 1699, to the 25th of Decemb. 1700](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A24599.0001.001/1:1?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=drawback)," that shows both the noun form and the verb form together.

[image]

> Rock Exported, part of the Sum above, which Duty was all **drawn back** and discharged by so much of the first Bonds given for the Rock.
>
> Which Duty was discharged by the **Draw|back** allowed, and satisfied by so many of the first Bonds given for the Rock.
>
> Rock Rest as Ballance at the Works, -- for which the Bonds are out and will be discharged if the Rock shall be melted, by the **Draw-back**, otherwise must be paid.

This *drawback* policy came with one of the Navigation Acts passed in the 17th century to regulate trade policies. I'm not a legal expert, but [a parliamentary law passed in 1695-6](https://www.british-history.ac.uk/statutes-realm/vol7/pp130-148) allows for drawbacks for salt:

> That all Salt made from Rock Salt (allowing the **Draw-back** for the same as in the said Act is mentioned) ...

This usage saturates the 2000+ results in the Eighteenth Century Collections Online database, with many mentions in histories, recorded debates of Parliament, and other sources.

The first usage cited in the Oxford English Dictionary for a meaning like "hindrance" seems to play off of this commercial meaning. Here's an excerpt from *The humourist: being essays upon several subjects* (1720):

> I am apt to think that every new Acquisition of Power, Wealth, or Fame, gives a new Touch and Bias to the Imagination. Ever since I began to be an Author, I have taken up an uncommon Passion for wearing of Ruffles; but, to shew how much the Philosopher in me gets the better of the proud Man, I have, at the same Time, as a **Drawback** upon my Ambition, laid aside my Silver Buckles, and contented myself with humble Bath-Metal.

The action of laying aside silver buckles acts as a way to restrain his ambition. The strict economic sense is stretched: he may be paying back one behavior for having previously *acquired* ambition in another, ruffled form. By the time literary author Samuel Richardson writes Clarissa, the meaning of *disadvantage* is clearer:

> 1747   S. Richardson Clarissa I. xiii. 73   Daughters were but incumbrances and **drawbacks** upon a family.

To the aspirational English patriarch in the 18th century, daughters require paying out wealth, constituting a drawback on family fortunes unless they comply with a patriarch's wishes and marry well.

Comment: This would make an excellent entry for etymology in: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drawback  If it's not of interest to you, I'd be happy to make the edit myself and credit your work.